# How do I get to my project in CleverMaps again?

Tags: clevermaps

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro CMShell % bash can_shell.sh                

              
              
              
   CLEVER°    
   MAPS'      
              
              

Version: 1.5.1-RELEASE

You are using an old version of CleverMaps Shell.
Version 1.5.2 is out, download here: https://developer.clevermaps.io/7537023/Download

1.5.2 - INFO: Fixed `importProject --prefix` that overrides metadata objects
1.5.2 - INFO: Added support for metric references
1.5.2 - INFO: Reviewed help messages for all commands
1.5.2 - INFO: Removed command alias `import`, use `importProject` instead
1.5.2 - INFO: Added a new command `cloneProject` for server-side project clonning

CleverMaps$ openProject --project xxxxxxxxxxx
Command 'openProject --project xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
CleverMaps$
```

This is what it says, can you please advise what's wrong? The project opened on this command the last time I used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you forget to login?

After shell starts simply type:

```
CleverMaps$ login
```

Also check the CleverMaps docs of login command configuration here: https://clevermaps-internal.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CDD/pages/7537214/Command+list

After successfull login you can use openProject command as you've tried.